# Phrase with similar meaning to "don't suffer fools gladly/lightly"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase that is similar to "he doesn't suffer fools gladly" it is something like "he'd sooner walk through you, than around" likely UK/Irish in origin.  I read it in an Irish paper a few years ago to describe someone who was impatient w people and didn't suffer fools lightly.  I cannot remember the exact phrase though.

Comment: Can you explain generically what phrases you've rejected?

Can you explain specifically how "he doesn't suffer fools gladly" might be paraphrased?

Can you explain how "he'd sooner walk through you, than around" could ever match anything about fools or gladness?

Comment: As @RobbieGoodwin said: How could "he'd sooner walk through you, than around" ever match anything about the idiom?"

Answer (score 1):

A **no-nonsense person**.

[no-nonsense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-nonsense) (MW)

> : tolerating no nonsense : serious, businesslike
>       a *no-nonsense* manager

[no-nonsense in American](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-nonsense)

> (ˈnoʊˈnɑnsɛns ; nōˈnänˈsens)
>   adjective
>   not indulging in or tolerating nonsense, impracticality, etc.; matter-of-fact; practical and serious

Usage:

> “He (James “Jim” Egan) was a no nonsense person – he didn't put up with fools.” --Don McLeod, Egan’s biographer

([U of T Libraries holds the Heritage Minutes archive at its Downsview facility](https://www.utoronto.ca/news/behind-scenes-new-heritage-minute-puts-spotlight-lgbtq-activist-jim-egan), University of Toronto - News)

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this is a very late answer, but I believe I know the Irish phrase you're looking for: "He'd go through you for a shortcut". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference to this in the Christian Bible in 1st Corinthians, I believe. Paul, the apostle is making a sarcastic remark to the Church of Corinth saying that they "suffer fools gladly because they are so wise".